# Using LibGit2Sharp in the Mono ASP.NET MVC project on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, mono, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I've created ASP.NET MVC project in MonoDevelop on Ubuntu.
Using Nuget, I added LibGit2Sharp package, but it doesn't have libgit2 library compiled for linux environment.
 
Then I downloaded [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2) sources and compiled them. 
Now I have libgit2-06d772d.so, but when I put it into the bin folder of my asp.net mvc project, I get System.DllNotFoundException git2-06d772d

**NOTE**
When I create Console project and put libgit2-06d772d.so into the bin folder of this project, application works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared objects are not loaded when they are next to a particular file, but when their directory is in the library load path. The operating system sets a few paths that are valid for all programs, but if you have your library elsewhere, you need to specify the directory yourself.

Exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the dir of the library will let the library loader know what other paths you expect to load a library from. E.g. if you built libgit2 with the libgit2sharp script you might run

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/libgit2sharp/libgit2/build
```

in the console to let the OS know that any program you start from that shell where to find libgit2.

It's common for mono-based apps to provide a script for the user to run which sets up the environment before calling mono to start the actual `.exe` with the program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help. If it's common for mono-based apps, then why it works fine when I create console application?

Comment: This is common for every single application on an unix system. `/usr/lib` is part of the standard load paths, so putting it there will make every program be able to find it.